# The isset function not working. Code within the block execute

Tags: php, session

I have two files project_status_discount_approval.php and project_status_disc_app.php.
In project_status_discount_approval.php: I have these lines:

**project_status_discount_approval.php**

```
echo '<p>APPROVAL FOR DISCOUNT</p>';
include('project_status_disc_app.php');
if (isset($_SESSION['formValidationErr'])) {
    _alert($errors); 
    unset($_SESSION['formValidationErr']);
}
```

I have placed the form and the form validation in project_status_disc_app.php and if there is any empty field it will populate the $_SESSION['formValidationErr'] and redirect back to project_status_discount_approval.php. This is the code that does that in project_status_disc_app.php:

```
$errors[] = 'Please fill up all fields before submitting';  
$_SESSION['formValidationErr'] = $errors;
header("Location: project_status.php?id=".$pid);
```

The intention is to execute the the two lines:

```
 _alert($errors); 
    unset($_SESSION['formValidationErr']);
```

within the if block in project_status_discount_approval.php only if the $_SESSION is assigned. However, now it gets executed even if the page gets loaded the for the first time. Can someone tell me what is causing this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `isset` doesn’t lie. Dump the content of $_SESSION before that `if`, and check what it actually contains at this point.

Comment: I'm not following this code. In `project_status_discount_approval.php`, you include `project_status_disc_app.php`. That file checks for errors and sets them in a session. Then it redirects the request to a third file `project_status.php`, which means that `if (isset($_SESSION['formValidationErr'])) {` (or anything after the include) will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `session_start()` before check if a variable of type $_SESSION is set or not.

You can read all about session managing in php:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how your session is handled in your file "project_status_disc_app.php". If you set it, even to null, isset will return true.
If you really want to restrict to the presence of something you should do this :

```
 if(isset($_SESSION["my_var"]) && !empty($_SESSION["my_var"])){ 
   // your code here
 }
```

Comment: _"If you set it, even to null, isset will return true."_ - That's incorrect. From [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) _"isset — Determine if a variable is declared **and is different than NULL**."_ - Anythng else would return `true` though (like empty string, empty array etc).

Comment: Also, using both empty and isset unnecessary. It's enough to use `!empty()` since that also checks if the variable is defined and not null.